# How to solve this limit?(n is a real number)

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^n-sin^n(x)}{x^{n+2}}$$
I tried to find a formula for nth derivative for both the numerator and denominator to apply l'hospital n times but i couldn t figure it out.